# How do I add a non-exchange email address to an Outlook distribution list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, distribution-list

Two members of our team work remotely and have emails that are not in our Outlook Exchange address book. We'd like to add them to a distribution list.

Normally, I would view the distribution list properties and click Modify Members > Add and search for them in the address book but of course they are not in this address list.

Is there a way to add arbitrary email address to an Outlook distribution list?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Contact for the person, then you should be able to add them to the distro list.